# Masters in Germany in Engineering

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, grades, germany

I am new here and am trying to find some answers. I have finished my BEng Hons in Mechanical and PowerPlant Systems from UK. During my studies I had to go through grievance and the depression for 2 years due to the death of my grandparents in consecutive years. This affected me and my grades very badly. I had to undergo counselling at university. I even had applied for Mitigating Circumstances to do my exams. Now, I have applied for Masters in Germany. I have sent 9 applications and got 7 rejected. And am waiting on reply from the 2. I have lost hope and I have not tried to explain why my grades were low. My grade is 3 according to uni-assist which doesn't open doors for admissions. But I want to do masters in germany and already have 1 year work experience. Will be having 2years of work experience when i apply for SS2017. Is there anyway I could compensate for my grade? And will the work experience be of any good? And do they actually consider explanation for bad grades? if so how to do it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you not explain your circumstances? I understand that you want to avoid the topic and do not want to justify your bad grades with something personal. But in your case, especially considering depression, I think that mentioning the reason for your low grades should rather help than damage your case. The key is to be honest, reflect on your past and give them a reason to let you in, e.g. you have overcome your depression and want to start over in your masters.

I don't think work experience matters much to be honest. Engineering in german universities is rather on the theoretical side as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my motivation letter but only briefly. Please do read. "My grades in my Bachelor's degree studies haven't been up to my expectations. I have been through a couple of personal problems due to which I had to undergo counselling at the university. I fell short of my expectations but I didn't give up. I finished my Bachelor's with the help of my professors and support staff at university. I am now more than determined to prove myself with a good master's degree thereby enhancing my skill set and knowledge." I was not aware if they'd accept it.  I am not sure of the procedure

Comment: lack of space. And could you be kind enough to guide me if there is such process? or do I just have to write an additional letter to explain it? And also do I have to provide any additional documents to support it?

Comment: Actually, your phrasing is pretty good and I believe that this would help. As far as I know the motivation letter should be enough. But keep in mind that if the masters program has a N.C. (numerus clausus) that you didn't achieve, they will probably reject you no matter how good your motivation letter is.

Comment: yeah, i think i have applied for NC programmes. Maybe i should look for ones with open admission. It is just hard to find anything with my current grades. Any suggestions on how to write a good letter of motivation?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert in motivation letters, but maybe these tips help: Keep it short (a page or less). Avoid saying things that are obvious ("I am motivated" -- of course you are! That's why you are writing the letter). Talk about what fascinates you about your subject and why you want to keep going.

I wish you good luck with your applications!